# Swift 3.0 compiler and Sourcekitservice memory allocation

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I just came across with a stranger problem in my iOS swift 3 project.

Scenarios:

I have a list os objects that the objets has a property as you can see bellow:

```
var total: Double {
    var sum = 0.0
    for item in self.products! {
        sum += item.price ?? 0
    }
    return sum
}
```

In the same class exists another property called distance:

```
var distance: Double?
```

My projects compilation works fine when I find the max value of distance, like that:

```
let minDistance = est?.max(by: { (e1, e2) -> Bool in
    return e1.distance! < e2.distance!
})
```

However, when I try find the max value prive, my project compilations become too slow and consumes a lot of memory in swift and sourcekitservice processes (more den 40 GB).

```
let maxValue = est?.max(by: { (e1, e2) -> Bool in
    return e1.total < e2.total
})
```

When I use a if let block it's works fine:

```
if let e = est {
    let minDistance = e.max(by: { (e1, e2) -> Bool in
        return e1.distance! < e2.distance!
    })
    let maxValue = est?.max(by: { (e1, e2) -> Bool in
        return e1.total < e2.total
    })
}
```

The problem in this case is when I use the objects minDistance! and maxValue. If I not use these variables the problem doesn't occur.

SourceKitService memory allocation:
[image]
[image]

Anybody already came across with a similar problem?